# Find UMVU estimator for P((0,1))

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

> Suppose a statistical model comprises all continuous distributions on $R^1$. Based on $n$ samples $x_i$, find a UMVU estimtor for $P((0,1))$, where $P$ is the true distribution.

I have three questions:

- In textbooks, I learned that a statistical model is denoted as $P_\theta$, indexed by $\theta\in \Omega$. Usually, $\theta$ is a scalar or vector value. In this question should I understand $\theta$ as an index for (uncountable) continuous distributions?
- In this case ($\theta$ is not a value), do we have something like MLE for inferring $\theta$?
- Intuitively, the solution to the question is $\frac{\sum_i 1(x_i\in (0,1))}{n}$. I can compute the variance ($\frac{p(1-p)}{n}$, where $p=P((0,1)$). How can I prove it's UMVU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be reduced to the two events $x\in(0,1)$ and $x\not\in(0,1)$, so you're effectively looking for a UMVU estimator for a Bernoulli variable. This is indeed the one you proposed, and it's UMVU by the [Lehmann–Scheffé theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmann%E2%80%93Scheff%C3%A9_theorem) because the number of successes is a complete and sufficient statistic for a Bernoulli variable.